# Create a table from an object jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to implement the following.

A user enters a sentence into a textbox following which a table is created. An example would be this.

Input: `"This is what I want to achieve"`

Result:

[image]

Currently, based on the code I have there is an object that looks like this:

```
{t: ["this", "to"], i: ["is", "i"], w: ["what", "want"], a: ["achieve"]};
```

Below is the current code I have ([also see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vq1qaavz/7/)).

I am able to take the input string and create a table with a row which has the first letter of each word.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="text-input" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="25">This is what I want to achieve</textarea>
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="words-header"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".calculate").click(function() {
    var result = {},
      arr = [];
    var array = $("#text-input").val().toLowerCase().split(" ");

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (typeof result[array[i][0]] == 'undefined') {
        result[array[i][0]] = [];
      }
      result[array[i][0]].push(arr[i]);
    }
    for (var key in result) {
      $(".words-header").append("<td>" + key.toUpperCase() + "</td>");
    }
  });
});
```

I believe the final table should look like this if it helps:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>I</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>achieve</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>this</td>
      <td>what</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td> </td>
       <td>i</td>
       <td>to</td>
       <td>want</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not a multidimensional Array, that's an Object with properties, and should be written that way: `{t:[...], i: [...], ...}`.

Comment: `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` makes no sense. Defeats purpose of `noConflict()` which is supposed to remove `$` alias

Comment: @blex i updated the question. Do you have any idea how I can implement this?

Comment: Really not clear what specific code problem is. *"I am having trouble.."* doesn't explain much

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question again to now contain an image as to how the table should look. Does this make it any clearer?

Comment: No not really . Create an [mcve] demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charlietfl i have updated the question with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way (Try it by clicking the *Run code snippet* button below):

```js
var app = app || {};
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var result, arr;

    app.initialize = {
        init: function() {
            app.splitWords.init();
        }
    };

    app.splitWords = {
        init: function() {
            $(".calculate").click(function() {
                result = [];
                arr = $("#text-input").val().split(" ");
                app.createMultiArray.init(arr);
            });
        }
    };

    app.createMultiArray = {
        init: function(array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var letter = array[i][0].toLowerCase();
                if (typeof result[letter] == 'undefined') {
                    result[letter] = [];
                }
                result[letter].push(array[i]);
            }
            // I added this method
            app.buildTable.init(result);
        }
    };

    app.buildTable = {
        init: function(result) {
            var headers  = Object.keys(result),
                max_rows = 0,
                rows_html = '';
            headers.sort();
            app.createHeaders.init(headers);
            // Determine how many rows you'll need
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                if(result[headers[i]].length > max_rows) { max_rows = result[headers[i]].length; }
            }
            // Loop "max_rows" times
            for (var i = 0; i < max_rows; i++) {
                rows_html += '<tr>';
                // Loop through all letters
                for(var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                  rows_html += '<td>';
                  if(i < result[headers[j]].length) {
                      rows_html += result[headers[j]][i];
                  }
                  rows_html += '</td>';
                }
                rows_html += '</tr>';
            }
            $(".words-header").after(rows_html);
        }
    };
  
    app.createHeaders = {
        init: function(headers) {
            // Empty the table in case of multiple tries
            $(".words-header").parent().html('<tr class="words-header"></tr>');
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                $(".words-header").append("<td>" + headers[i].toUpperCase() + "</td>");
            }
        }
    };

    app.docOnReady = {
        init: function() {
            app.initialize.init();
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(app.docOnReady.init);

})(jQuery);
```

```css
#results-table table{ border-collapse: collapse; } #results-table td{ border: 1px solid #000; padding: .2em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text-input" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="25">This is what I want to achieve</textarea>
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>

<div id="results-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="words-header"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this is amazing @blex